# Load and parse URL via JS in the background

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, steam

Currently I am trying to develop a little Firefox extension.

In detail: i want to display users from the site dota2lounge.com the current prize of their steam items on the steam community market. My idea was to do this via a Firefox extension which reads the item names from the HTML code on dota2lounge.com . Via JS i would like to search the steam community market for the item names and parse the current prize. This should happen without any further action from the user and without opening extra tabs/windows.

In java i would just load the site into a variable and work with it. How could i do this with JS (or Jquery)? Or maybe there is an even better way in the addon-sdk from firefox which could solve this issue.

Any thoughts and hints are welcome.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Cross-Site-Prevention doesn't allow to access foreign domains from JavaScript. Just try to load the URL with an XMLHttpRequest and see for yourself.

Comment: I'd check out csgolounge.com's source code and check how they're doing it. Also found this library (which I had hoped to play around with someday) https://github.com/eknowles/node-steam-tradeoffers

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall you can't use nodejs code in an extension.

Comment: In a Firefox extension you *can* do cross-site requests, FYI: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/request

Comment: And I'm pretty sure you can also run nodejs code using [browserify](http://browserify.org/).

Comment: This is a question about browser extensions - node.js isn't relevant.

Comment: @jangxx The link was relevant for the steam api part of the question. Good to know about node though. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be pretty simple to do using the Add-on SDK. Here is a list of modules you should look at:

1. the request module will allow you to make requests to other sites: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/request
2. while the request module is fine, what you may want to do instead to get info from the steam site is use the page-worker module to load the site and easily extract info from it using jQuery. This is much nicer than using regex. The code would look something like this gist:

https://gist.github.com/canuckistani/6c299c812bbe582d9efb

Comment: I guess the second aproach suites best here. Let me see if i understand that one correct: In my Add-On Script i can gather specific data from the current site. Now i can call the Content Script, in this case my worker, with the collected data. The worker will do a request to the steam community market, gather the desired information and send a message to my Add-on Script via the Port Modul. Is this correct?

Comment: I think so, yeah. Think of the worker as an invisible browser you can load, inject a script into and gather info from.

Comment: thank you. i will try to read my way through the page-worker and some other things on the Firefox dev guides, since i am completly new to this enviroment.